# Spring Data JPA. Getting all pages from Pageable

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a SpringBoot app and an interface that extends from `CrudRepository`

```
@Query("select cps from HotelPriceSummary cps where cps.price > 5 and cps.profilePercentage >= 70 ")
List<HotelPriceSummary> findMine(Pageable pageable);
```

I would like to know if it is possible to get the total number of pages from the object `Pageable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Page<T>` Interface which returns the total elements.

> long  - `getTotalElements()`
>
> Returns the total amount of elements.

You can find more in the docs:
[Page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) and 
[PageImpl](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.html).

In your example it should work like that:

```
@Query("select cps from HotelPriceSummary cps where cps.price > 5 and cps.profilePercentage >= 70 ")
Page<HotelPriceSummary> findMine(Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should extend your repository from `PagingAndSortingRepository` instead of `CrudRepository`. Then the method query should be:

```
@Query("select cps from HotelPriceSummary cps where cps.price > 5 and cps.profilePercentage >= 70 ")
Page<HotelPriceSummary> findMine(Pageable pageable);
```

After that, you can use the query from a service (or whatever you want) and then `getTotalPages()` in the response. Example:

```
int page = 0, pageSize = 10;    
Page<HostelPriceSummary> response = myRepo.findMine(PageRequest.of(page, pageSize));
int numberOfPages =  response.getTotalPages();
```